# IFTTT Particle Photon Triggering Phillips Hue: Values Failing

Tags: philips-hue, ifttt

I want a Particle Photon to trigger the IFTTT action of a Phillips Hue light changing brightness to either 0%, 25%, 50%, etc.  The event seems to be triggering, but the brightness does not change as expected.

On Particle Console, the Integrations section, I created a new integration:

---

Event Name: set_hue
URL: https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/set_hue/with/key/MY_REAL_LIFE_KEY
Request Type: POST
Request Format: Web Form
Device: Any

Advanced Settings > Form Fields > Custom
Value1: {{Value1}}

Http Headers
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

---

On my Photon, I run the following:

```cpp
void setup() {

}

void loop() {
  static int brightness = 25;
  // Get some data
  String Value1 = String(brightness);
  brightness = (brightness + 25) % 125;
  // Trigger the integration
  Particle.publish("set_hue", Value1, PRIVATE);
  // Wait 3 seconds
  delay(3000);
}
```

In my events log, I can see things like: 
Name Data Device Published At
hook-response/set_hue/0 Congratulations! You've fired the set_hue event particle-internal   6/2/19 at 6:58:14 pm
hook-sent/set_hue       particle-internal   6/2/19 at 6:58:14 pm
set_hue 50  6/2/19 at 6:58:13 pm

Any ideas why this doesn't seem to affect the brightness on my Hue?

Comment: Been 2 years. Maybe you got it to work. If so, it maybe good to let us know what happened.